# I'm not able to step up terms in fibonacci sequence python

Tags: python, fibonacci

I want to print every fourrth term of the fibonacci seq until n terms however i'm very confused why this code isnt working, I first have a function to calculate n terms and then another function to iterate and step for every 4th term.

```
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term
def fibo_sequence(n):

# first two terms
    n1, n2 = 0, 1
    count = 0

# check if the number of terms is valid
    if n <= 0:
        print("Please enter a positive integer")
# if there is only one term, return n1
    elif n == 1:
        print("Fibonacci sequence upto",n,":")
        print(n1)
# generate fibonacci sequence
    else:
        print("Fibonacci sequence:")
        while count < n:
            print(n1)
            nth = n1 + n2
            # update values
            n1 = n2
            n2 = nth
            count += 1


def fibo_skipper(n):
    #fibo_sequence(n)
    for term in fibo_sequence(n):
        for i in range(0, n, 4):
            print(i)





n = 8  #Enter the nth term here

fibo_skipper(n) # Print the print every fourth item of the Fibonacci sequence upto n
```

Comment: You should show the expected and actual output to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `print` at the lowest level, so it is not possible to filter anything from a higher level. If you want to be able to filter, the low  `fibo_sequence(n)` function should not print anything but should return a sequence. A simple way would be to use a list:

```
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term
def fibo_sequence(n):
    seq = []

# first two terms
    n1, n2 = 0, 1
    count = 0

# check if the number of terms is valid
    if n <= 0:
        print("Please enter a positive integer")
# if there is only one term, return n1
    elif n == 1:
        print("Fibonacci sequence upto",n,":")
        seq.append(n1)
# generate fibonacci sequence
    else:
        print("Fibonacci sequence:")
        while count < n:
            seq.append(n1)
            nth = n1 + n2
            # update values
            n1 = n2
            n2 = nth
            count += 1
    return seq
```

But it would still not follow good encapsulation pratices, because the same function shows messages and build the sequence. You should only build the sequence (optionaly an empty list) and let the caller decide what to display if the length of the returned list is 0 or 1.

If you want to go further, you should considere to build a generator that would `yield` the values one at a time, and because of that would avoid to store them.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: I wrote an answer starting from the assumption that your `fibo_sequence` was actually returning a `sequence`... my bad.

Clearly, the natural case is that you have some sort of fibonacci calculation (i.e. returning a sequence, using a generator) returning a treatable output, as many of the solutions suggest.

In any case, you can still do what you like even having a function printing to screen, temporarily redirecting `sys.stdout`

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

def fibo_skipper(n, step = 4):
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = StringIO()
    fibo_sequence(n)
    lines = sys.stdout.getvalue().split("\n")[1:] # [1:] is to skip first line
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    # slice operator will split your lines every n elements
    print(lines[::step])


fibo_skipper(100)
```

It is important to highlight that I am not suggesting this approach (which goes beyond your original question) but, in situations when you do not have full control of the called method (in your case, `fibo_sequence`), this can still get you where you need to.

As a side note, I think you can be more compact the `else` statement:

```
else:
    print("Fibonacci sequence:")
    while count < n:
        print(n1)
        # update values
        n1, n2 = n2, n1 + n2
        count += 1
```

Comment: `fibo_sequence` at the moment returns `None` as it just prints the values on-the-fly. You either need to build a list of the numbers and return that for slicing, or add a condition to the function to only print every 4th term.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code structure, you should check that the `n-th` element is divisible by 4 before printing it, and you can check it with the modulus operator `%`

```
...
# generate fibonacci sequence
    else:
        print("Fibonacci sequence:")
        while count < n:
            if count % 4 == 0:
                print(n1)
            nth = n1 + n2
            # update values
            n1 = n2
            n2 = nth
            count += 1
```

This way you still calculate the series and prints only each 4th element.

If you want the skip size to be a parameter you can pass it to you function:

```
def fibo_sequence(n, skip):
...
# generate fibonacci sequence
    else:
        print("Fibonacci sequence:")
        while count < n:
            if count % skip == 0:
                print(n1)
            nth = n1 + n2
            # update values
            n1 = n2
            n2 = nth
            count += 1
```

Notice that this code structure is less robust to changes.

Answer (score 0):

You would call the skipper function in main. The skipper function calls sequence function, which returns a list of fibo numbers. The for loops print these number in interval of 4.

```
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term
def fibo_sequence(n):   
    l = []
    # first two terms
    n1, n2 = 0, 1
    count = 0

    # check if the number of terms is valid
    if n <= 0:
        print("Please enter a positive integer")
    # if there is only one term, return n1
    elif n == 1:
        print("Fibonacci sequence upto",n,":")
        l.append(n1)
    # generate fibonacci sequence
    else:
        print("Fibonacci sequence:")
        while count < n:
            l.append(n1)
            nth = n1 + n2
            # update values
            n1 = n2
            n2 = nth
            count += 1
    return l

def fibo_skipper(n):
    l = fibo_sequence(n)
    for i in range(0, n, 4):
        print(l[i])


n = int(input())
fibo_skipper(n)
```

Comment: It should be like if n=8, then the output shoule be 2, 13 ...

Answer (score -2):

My First Answer was Garbage, here you go:

```
def fibo_sequence(n):

    n1, n2 = 0, 1
    count = 0
    seq = []

   if n <= 0:
       print("Please enter a positive integer")
   
   elif n == 1:
       print("Fibonacci sequence upto",n,":")
       print(n1)
   else:
       print("Fibonacci sequence:")
       while count < n:
           print(n1)
           seq.append(n1)
           nth = n1 + n2
           # update values
           n1, n2 = n2, nth
           count += 1

   if len(seq) != 0:
       return seq

def fibo_skipper(n):
    print("Every 4th Number in Fibo up to n:  ")
    seq = fibo_sequence(n)
    for el in seq:
        print(seq[el*4])

n = 10  
fibo_skipper(n)
```

Comment: It's still not working :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).